# Triangle problem about a point

Tags: geometry, triangles

**Question**:

> If D is a point on the side AB of ABC, find a point X on BC such that the triangles XAD and CAX are equal in area.

**My attempt**:

I don't actually know how do I solve this problem. I could draw a line parallel to AC from D which may then intersect at X on BC, but that doesn't actually solve the problem.

How do I solve this problem (hints would be great) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see if this works. find the midpoint $E$ of $CD$. then the point $X$ you are looking for is point where $AE$ and $BC$ meet.

Comment: I don't know if it works. How do I prove the triangles equal in area after this step?

Comment: @gaurang tandon, drop perpendiculars from $CY$ and $DZ$ to $AX.$ now, look at the two congruent right angle triangles $CWY$ and $DWZ$ where $W$ the point of intersection of $CD$ and $AX.$ you have $CY = DZ$ twice area of $AXC = AX*YX = AX*BZ =$ twice the area of $AXD.$

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thanks!